# $ \dot{x}(t)=A(t)x+B(t),\quad x(0)=x_0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $A\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}),B\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R^{n}})$. Prove that there exists a unique solution of the IVP
$$
\dot{x}(t)=A(t)x+B(t),\quad x(0)=x_0
$$

An exercise in my tectbook is like this. I wonder whether it means to prove the existence of a unique global solution. If so, how can I solve it. I just learned the Picard Theorem, and it is about local condition, so I am confused.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What did Picard theorem says and can you apply it in this situation?

Comment: Multiply both members by $\exp\left(\int\mathrm{A}\left(t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$.

Comment: According to the Picard Theorem, we can only know there is a unique solution $x$ in a small interval, but the problem seems ask me to find a global solution. Additionally, if $t$ is limited in a small interval, how do I know the initial value $x_0$ is a proper  initial value? A complete proof of the problem may be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixMarin : That does only work if $A$ is constant or in the very rare case that all possible $A(t)$ commute with each other.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are right. It appears frequently in Many Body Theory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the way the question is worded, $A(t)$ is a matrix $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

To apply Picard's theorem, the rhs needs to satisfy a Lipshitz condition: $$|A(t)x_1+B(t)-A(t)x_2-B(t)|=|A(t)(x_1-x_2)|\le\|A(t)\||x_1-x_2|\le c|x_1-x_2|$$ since $A(t)$ (and its coefficients) are continuous in $t$, so $$\|A(t)\|^2\le\sum_{i,j}|A_{ij}(t)|^2\le c^2$$ on some neighborhood of the initial $t=0$.